# Redis: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'auth' command

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm using `redis` with nodejs. Version: `"redis": "^3.1.2"`

When my server connects to redis, I get the following error:

```
ERR wrong number of arguments for 'auth' command
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the URL, which looks like this:

```
redis://h:<password>@<url>:<port>
```

My redis is hosted by Heroku and I'm unable to change the URL. And have no idea how can I make it work. Any ideas/solutions much appreciated.

Comment: Redis 3.1.2 has breaking changes. Above URL works till  redis@^3.0.2

Comment: Here is the release note from Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1932 . Please remove the username from the URL string present in the env variable of Heroku. It should look like redis://password_goes_here@host_goes_here:port_goes_here

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Redis Version < 6.0.0 and [node-redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis) >=3.1.0  , `redis://h:<password>@<url>:<port>` will not work and throw `ERR wrong number of arguments for 'auth' command`.

Solution: `redis://:<password>@<url>:<port>` works ie: **remove username from the URL**.
Note:- The ":" before the `<password>`

This should fix the problem that you are facing.

For other versions:

Redis Version < 6.0.0 and [node-redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis) <=3.0.2  , `redis://h:<password>@<url>:<port>` works.

Redis Version >= 6.0.0 and node-redis(any version), both `redis://<username>:<password>@<url>:<port>`(when username in redis ACL is set to custom username) and  `redis://<password>@<url>:<port>` will work.

The reason is:

- node-redis made the changes to support Redis-6, as per [releasenote](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis/releases/tag/v3.1.0).
- Redis-6 supports username in ALC. Before v6, Redis did not include the notion of users, and the only authentication strategy was a single login password. [Reference](https://redislabs.com/blog/getting-started-redis-6-access-control-lists-acls/)
- Whenever you attach Redis addon to Heroku container, the environment variable REDIS_URL is set and the value is Connection URL of format: `redis://h:<password>@<url>:<port>`. This "h" is a fake/dummy/placeholder username because some clients(eg: node-redis) could not correctly handle a blank username in the URL.   After the release of ACLs in Redis 6, clients began to support the new AUTH command that uses 2 arguments (username and password). Clients that attempt to pass the h username to the AUTH will result in an above error on Redis versions 4 and 5. [Reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1932)

Comment: Thank you. For others that might see this, I did a simple regex to remove the "h" in the URL provided by Heroku.

Comment: We just ran into this because `promise-redis` (would not recommend at this point), includes `node-redis` with a `*` dependency resolution. We are running Redis 5.0 right now, and so the update from 3.0 to 3.1 in a completely unrelated change broke our AUTH commands with a username within it.

Thanks for the awesome explanation!

Comment: Just a comment,

Solution: `redis://<password>@<url>:<port>` works ie: remove username from the URL.

should be: 

Solution: `redis://:<password>@<url>:<port>` works ie: remove username from the URL.

You need a `:` before the password.

Comment: @shernshiou you are right this: `redis://:<password>@<url>:<port>` worked well for me